# Exception Decoding Bitmap Error in Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, android-emulator

I have an application that is having some buttons that implement some features.

Two of them is:

1. Share Image - The images provided by the app which users can share.
2. "Set As" - Users cal also utilize "set as" features (Set As
       wallpaper, contact picture, etc.).

The app isn't live currently, so I tested it's apk on my mobile and 2-3 other Android mobiles. The app is running correctly only on my device, but here's what I found,

1. "Share" and "Set As" isn't working on emulator - Log cat ERROR shown below. Here's the sdk,

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "my package name"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   ```

   }
2. "Share" and "Set As" working perfectly on my Android mobile -
   Android 5.0. It creates a folder in "Phone Storage" and saves image
       according to my code shown below.
3. "Share" and "Set As" isn't working on Android 6.0. It is not even creating folder.

**"Log cat ERROR FOR Emulator... i..e point 1 above"**

- Error after clicking "Share" in Emulator

java.io.FileNotFoundException: "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/myimg.png";: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

- Error after clicking "Set As" in Emulator

  08-22 21:27:34.526 2208-2208/? E/UriImage: got exception decoding bitmap 
                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                             at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
                                             at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
                                             at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
                                             at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
                                             at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
                                             at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
                                             at com.android.camera.CropImage.onCreate(CropImage.java:143)
                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)

**Integer Arrays for images**

```
 Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
       .
       .
       .
```

}

**SHARE BUTTON code snippet**

```
           // Here, I am getting images from the Integer array I created
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageIDs[i]);

            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            // Creates new folder with name "MyFolder"
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/");
            dir.mkdirs();

            // Image saves with the following name
            File file = new File(dir, "myimg.png");
```

**"Set As" button code snippet**

```
    // Here, I am getting images from the Integer array I created
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageIDs[i]);

    Rest code I added from the following thread on Stack Overflow:
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096164

    Here, I have added the following path:
      String absolutepath="/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/myimg.png";
```